# Looking for a programm for sound_capturing,sound source localization, source separation and automatic speech recognition

Tags: ros, audio

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As the title says, i am looking for a program which in collaboration with ROS, it can sound_capture,sound source localize, source separate and automatic speech recognise...I have already found:

- Hark
- Roar

Any suggestions....?
Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199128/looking-for-a-programm-for-sound_capturing,sound-source-localization,-source-separation-and-automatic-speech-recognition/) by [lefos99](https://answers.ros.org/users/21056/lefos99/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2014-12-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For recognizers you can also check out [gspeech](http://wiki.ros.org/gspeech) and [pocketsphinx](http://wiki.ros.org/pocketsphinx).

And [audiocapture](http://wiki.ros.org/audio_capture) for recording audio.

---

Originally posted by [csherstan](https://answers.ros.org/users/9751/csherstan/) with karma: 122 on 2014-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cyril Jourdan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4040/cyril-jourdan/) on 2014-12-10**:
I could get the pocketsphinx working fine, but not gspeech. It seems that google API v1 has been closed, and that we have to use v2 with a key. Does anyone managed to get that working ?